# Speed up and simplify multiple if/else with regex machers

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have [Scheme based lips interpreter written in JavaScript](https://lips.js.org/), and inside the parser I have single function for parsing the values. Inside S-Expressions:

```js
function parse_argument(arg) {
    var regex = arg.match(re_re);
    if (regex) {
        return new RegExp(regex[1], regex[2]);
    } else if (arg.match(/^"[\s\S]*"$/)) {
        return parse_string(arg);
    } else if (arg.match(char_re)) {
        return parse_character(arg);
    } else if (arg.match(rational_re)) {
        return parse_rational(arg);
    } else if (arg.match(complex_re)) {
        return parse_complex(arg);
    } else if (arg.match(int_re)) {
        return parse_integer(arg);
    } else if (arg.match(float_re)) {
        return parse_float(arg);
    } else if (arg === 'nil') {
        return nil;
    } else if (['+nan.0', '-nan.0'].includes(arg)) {
        return LNumber(NaN);
    } else if (['true', '#t', '#true'].includes(arg)) {
        return true;
    } else if (['false', '#f', '#false'].includes(arg)) {
        return false;
    } else if (arg.match(/^#[iexobd]/)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid numeric constant');
    } else {
        // characters with more than one codepoint
        var m = arg.match(/#\\(.+)/);
        if (m && ucs2decode(m[1]).length === 1) {
            return parse_character(arg);
        }
        return parse_symbol(arg);
    }
}
```

this function is called a lot while parsing so getting rid of if..else will probably speed up the code, but I'm not sure if it can be simplified or speed up.

Do you know any way to make this function run faster? As you can see symbol is at the end, and while parsing symbols are most common object.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you stick with this, you ought to sort the sequence by the probability of encounter.  For instance, left and right paren, atom names and small decimal numbers are by far the most frequent tokens in LISP in my experience; they should be the earliest things in your list.    If you want it to uniformly faster, see my answer.

Comment: .. if you want your scheme to go fast in a browser, you might consider porting a native-code compiling scheme to Web Assembly.   There even appears to be one already: https://github.com/google/schism

Comment: @Toto I've added to codereview first but almost no one even viewed the post. So I've asked here.

Answer (score 2):

@georg's answer is pretty good, ff all OP wants is to pull up the lexeme text for a wide variety of lexemes.  This combines all the separate regexes into a single regex and that will efficiently handle the conditionals.

However, if OP wants to produce special codes to say which lexeme type ("token") has been recognized (see his recognizers for nil/true/false; I suspect it of the other tokens but OP didn't provide enough code) then what OP needs is a traditional lexer generator that classifies to tokens.

The difference is that @georg's union regext has a single "accept" state ("very complex regex matched one of its (union) subterms") vs lexer generators, that have one accept state for **each** subterm.   Having separate accept states allows corresponding separate actions, such as as producing a lexeme-specific token code and optionally doing value conversion (e.g. reading the floating point number text and producing a floating point value).  Using a lexer generator is that standard solution used by virtually every compiler/interpreter because of this ability.

OP can look up any "Javascript lexer generator" with Google, but here's one:
https://github.com/sormy/flex-js   I have no specific experience with it.

Note: if OP goes this way, he should put *all* of his lexemes into the lexer generator, esp.  "(" and ")" for LISP, rather than using it for just values.  Then each single call on a "get_token" routine can return the next token.

Comment: I agree that in general a hand-written or generated lexer or lexer-parser would be more flexible and powerful than a regex + parser. In this particular case, the OP might even consider implementing `read` in their LISP itself, thus making it self-containing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already use `Lexer` in my code (it's simple state machine) but right  now it test only special cases that need to parsed differently (like comments, block comments, block symbols or regular expressions) And I handle everything that is not special as symbol that is handled by `parse_argument` that is last step of the `Lexer`.  It will be hard to rewrite complex regular expressions into `Lexer` rules. That's why when I replaced single big regex tokenizer with Lexer I left `parse_argument` function.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to have one big regex with all tokens ORed together, so that the regex engine does the branching itself. This is (should be) faster, and also helps simplifying the subsequent `parse_xxx` stuff since you already have sub-matches you need. A toy example:

```js
let LEXEMS = String.raw`
    (?<num>
        [0-9]+
        (?<frac> \. [0-9]+) ?
    )
    |
    (?<ident>
        \w+
    )
    |
    (?<op>
        [+ * / -]
    )
    |
    \s+
    |
    (? <ERROR> \S)
`;

let lexer = new RegExp(LEXEMS.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 'g')

//

program = "abc + 123.456 - 123"

for (let m of program.matchAll(lexer)) {
    let g = m.groups;

    if (g.num)
        console.log('num', g.num, 'frac=', g.frac)
    if (g.ident)
        console.log('ident', g.ident)
    // etc


}
```

Comment: This is better than OP's explicit if-else in that the regex's are efficiently matched.  It suffers from the same "else if" chain effect because it doesn't directly tell you which token it matched; you have (as your example does) test for each one.

Comment: That's true, but unlike regexp matches, these boolean checks are very lightweight.